# First steps in building Switching power supplies

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I want to make a 50Amps switching power supply, I have already done 10A linear ones succesfully

This time it has to be a switching power supply one so, any ideas or tips of where to start are appreciated

IF I succed and works as intended this will end up being used to power a high power laser at a research center, but if I fail nothing bad will happen, I just want to have the chance to work in this project and as I said, I do this more for the experience than anything

I do know its not an impossible task, but not a trivial one, either however I need some ideas of where to start

Comment: Did your shift key break?  Earlier today it was working.

Comment: 50A at what voltage?  High power switch mode power supplies are not trivial but certainly achievable.

Comment: @NickAlexeev it looks like the only emphasis he wanted was on "IF" haha. Maybe it's a hidden writing style.

Comment: 12v, i was wondering about the possibility of making it variable but i sill dont know if this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an in-depth/academic approach to learning about the theory behind switching power supplies, the [power electronics class](https://www.coursera.org/course/powerelectronics) on Coursera is a good place to start. You'd probably only need to take the first six weeks unless you want to design the controller too. You will need a decent background in analog circuit theory (undergrad EE is fine). Doing the homework will *vastly* improve your understanding.